# Reestablish link between path dependent type and its parent at runtime?

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

I am experimenting with path dependent types.  In my simple example I am using a Currency object to ensure that Money calculations can only be performed on Money of the same currency.

```
// Simple currency class
case class Currency(code: String, name: String, symbol: String) {

  // Money amounts in this currency
  // Operations are only supported on money of the same currency
  case class Money(amount: BigDecimal) {
    override def toString: String = s"$code $amount"

    val currency: Currency.this.type = Currency.this

    def +(rhs: Money): Money = Money(amount + rhs.amount)

    def -(rhs: Money): Money = Money(amount - rhs.amount)
  }
}
```

Using the above class simple calulations in the repl are straigh forward.

```
val e1 = Euro.Money(5)
val e2 = Euro.Money(9)
e1 + e2 // Compiles fine

val d1 = Dollar.Money(6)
d1 + e2 // Doesn't compile as expected
```

These are simple because the compiler can easily prove that e1 and e2 share a common currency.  However proving that money instances share a common currency is much harder when I read a list of money amounts from a file or database.  For instance I cannot see how to implement the collate function below.

```
trait CurrencyAndMonies {
  val currency: Currency
  val monies: List[currency.Money]
}

// Take a list of money in different currencies and group them by currency
// so their shared Currency type is available to static type checking
// in further calculations
def collate(Seq[Currency#Money]): List[CurrencyAndMonies] = ???
```

Is it possible to sort monies based on currency and reestablish the link between them? And if so how? I don't mind changing the signature or the way Money amounts are read from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can downcast:

```
new CurrencyAndMonies {
  val currency = foo
  val monies = bars.map(_.asInstanceOf[currency.Money])
}
```

Group by `Money#currency`.

The downcast is not runtime-checked, so you'll have to make sure the monetary value has the right currency (which you already do by grouping by currency), but it will compile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are right that I will have to cast it, which is a pity.  I am looking at the neatest way of casting it at the moment (maybe placing it behind pattern matching for safety).

Answer (score 1):

In your example type signature

```
   def collate(Seq[Currency#Money]): List[CurrencyAndMonies]
```

doesn't require all money to be from the same currency, it can be random Money from any Currency.

```
  val Euro = Currency("EUR", "Euro", "EUR")
  val USD = Currency("USD", "Dollar", "$")

  def collateOld(s: List[Currency#Money]): CurrencyAndMonies = ???

  // Compiles successfully -> ERROR
  collateOld(List(USD.Money(10), Euro.Money(20)))
```

Typically you'll have to pass and instance of currency as well as list of Money. For example you can do it this way:

```
  abstract class CurrencyAndMonies(val currency: Currency) {
    type Money
    def monies: List[Money]
  }

  def collate(c: Currency)
             (m: List[c.Money]): CurrencyAndMonies { type Money = c.Money } =
    new CurrencyAndMonies(c) {
      type Money = c.Money
      val monies = m
    }


  collate(Euro)(List(Euro.Money(10), Euro.Money(20)))
```

It's weird that it's required to re-define type Money inside CurrencyAndMonies, but I can't understand why just currency.Money doesn't work. If you'll make constructor private and collate only one way to create instance of a class you should be good to use in with guaranteed type safety

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I wanted to be able to collate monies with multiple different currencies.  Because when you read them from a file the compile time link between a Money instance and its Currency is broken.  I want to reestablish this link, so my operations become safe again.

Comment: aaah, got it, I misunderstood original question